# Remove label Search terms from Views exposed form

Tags: 7, views, theming

On [this site](http://www.bo-medical.com) in the sidebar i have a `views_exposed_form` to search. I need this search functionality to show my search results for restricted pages.

- How do i remove the label 'Search Terms'. Is it possible within
  `template.php` with a hook?
- How do i add a placeholder to the input field?

Comment: You can do this by adding form_alter hook in custom module.

Answer (score 2):

```
function views_exposed_form($form, &$form_state) {

if ($info = $handler->exposed_info()) {
          $form['#info']["$type-$id"] = $info;
          /**enter your code here  *****/


        }
/**for place holer**/


if (isset($form['title'])) {
        $form['title'][] = array('#placeholder' => t('Gemeente...'));
}




}
```

Comment: it's not working? I tried it in `template.php`

Answer (score 0):

> **Remove label :** In exposed form settings there is a label text if you will not add any value on that it will not display any label

```
    /* for placeholder */ 

    function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
     if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
                    $form['title']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Place holder');

    }
    }
```

Comment: above code i placed in `template.php` but i don't see a placeholder..

Comment: Please add your code what you have written in template.php